# shell script : if array value was greater than a number then run a command

Tags: arrays, shell

i have a a files containing usernames and users sent count mail per line . for example (dont know how many line have ) :

info.txt >

```
500 example1
40 example2
20 example3
....
..
.
```

if the number was greater than X , i want to run commands containing the user name and act on user .

```
getArray() {
       users=() # Create array
       while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
      do
          users+=("$line") # Append line to the array
       done < "$1"
    }
    getArray "/root/.myscripts/spam1/info.txt"


   # i know this part is incorrect and need help here :
    if [ "${users[1$]}" -gt "50" ]

    then

echo "${users[2$] has sent ${users[1$]} emails"


fi
```

please Help

Thanks

Comment: `"${users-count-mail[@]}"` expands to the list of every user, which is clearly not what you want.   Why are you reading everything into an array at all?  Just read the data, and act on it when you read it.  That is a much simpler design.

Comment: because i dont know how many lines i have in txt files .

Comment: please look at the script again i have change it to simpler design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing how many lines of input you have is no reason to use an array.  Indeed, it is generally more useful if you assume your input is infinite (an input stream), so reading into an array is impossible.  Just read each line and take action if necessary:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r count user; do
  if test "$count" -gt 50; then   
    echo "$user has sent $count emails"
  fi   
done < /root/.myscripts/spam1/info.txt
```